# What kind of differential equation is this one and how to solve it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

On working on a physical problem that is of interest to me, I arrived at a differential equation that I desperately need to solve$$\frac{dy}{dt}+c y=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$ where c is constant and y is the unknown function that I need to solve for.
I don't know if such an equation fall under a known class of differential equations, since it contain both ordinary and partial derivative operators.  Note: I arrived at this equation from this one: $\frac{dy}{dt}+c y=\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}$ where $\theta$ is unknown function that I know it can only be function of time, hence $\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}$, so $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\frac{d\theta}{dt}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}\frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$ and hence the equation in the question above, is there any problem with this reasoning in the first place?

Comment: The partial derivative comes into play, if $y$ depends on several variables. Otherwise total and partial derivative are the same and you end up with $y = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your observation ''$\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} \frac{\partial \theta}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$'' is not quite correct. To see this, we consider the different number of variables the function $y$ can have.

Suppose $y$ is a function of $\theta$ only. If $\theta$ itself is a function of $t$, $y$ is a function of $t$ only (through $\theta$). For clarity, we introduce $Y(t) = y(\theta(t))$. Then, we have
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} Y}{\text{d} t} = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} y(\theta(t)) = \frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d} \theta}\,\frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t}.
\end{equation}
As you can see, no partial derivatives are necessary, since all the functions involved each depend on one variable only.

Now, suppose $y$ is a function of both $\theta$ and $t$, so we write $y(\theta,t)$. Now, you have reason to assume that $\theta$ itself is a function of $t$. If we plug that into $y$, then $y$ depends on $t$ *only* -- albeit in a more complex fashion, both explicitly through its second variable, and implicitly through the $t$-dependence of $\theta$. For clarity, we introduce $\eta(t) = y(\theta(t),t)$. Then, we have
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} \eta}{\text{d} t} = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} \Big[y(\theta(t),t)\Big] = \frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t}\,\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} + \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}.
\end{equation}

So, taking your equation
\begin{equation}
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} y + c y = \frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta},
\end{equation}
we see that the right hand side can be written as
\begin{equation}
 \frac{\text{d} \theta}{\text{d} t}\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} t} y - \frac{\partial y}{\partial t},
\end{equation}
leading to the equation
\begin{equation}
 c y = - \frac{\partial y}{\partial t}.
\end{equation}
Therefore, we know that $y$ can be written as
\begin{equation}
 y(\theta,t) = f(\theta) e^{-c t}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Many thanks man, your answer is so clear and apparently consistent with my system that I have already solved numerically, should I be able to determine $f(\theta)$ from the initial conditions?

Comment: Thanks! Without ODE involving $\frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta}$ it might get tricky to get $f(\theta)$ -- unless you've got something like $y(\theta,0) = g(\theta)$.